# Solution to the Schrodinger equation for periodically time dependent Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, simulations

I have a Hamiltonian which is time dependent but possesses periodic symmetry: $H(t+t_0)=H(t)$.  Is there any clever techniques to exploit this?  Edit: In particular, I would like a practical method to simulate the dynamics of such a system (as opposed to naive time-slicing).

Comment: Do you want dynamics or average ground state?

Comment: @JoeFitzsimons -- good question.  This was an example question I used at a StackExchange participation drive, so I unfortunately didn't give it much thought.  I will make it clearer now.

Comment: http://qols.ph.ic.ac.uk/~sbuhmann/docs/lectures/AnalyticalMethods3.pdf Barring some typos, a lucid introduction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the formalism of Floquet space. The basic idea is that one uses a time-independent but infinite dimensional Hamiltonian to simulate evolution under a time-dependent but finite dimensional Hamiltonian by using a new index to label terms in a Fourier series.

A good, short introduction can be found in [Levante et al](http://www.informaworld.com/10.1080/00268979500102671). For more details, [Leskes et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/B6THC-50DYH0S-1/2/52572a0c4adbd19ac8250b82ea773dd8) provides a very through review. Finally, a simple example of an application of Floquet theory is given by [Bain and Dumont](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cmr.1006/abstract).

Comment: Chris, can you add some comments about truncating the series in order to implement this method?

Comment: @ChrisFerrie Another paper about Floquet theory: Shirley JH. Solutions of the Schrodinger equation with a Hamiltonian periodic in time. Phys Rev 1965; 138:B979-B987.